# Purchasing one item multiple times in TInApppurchase in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, in-app-purchase, itunes, delphi-xe6

I have developed an application with Delphi XE6 including inappPurchase, I have defined the product as 'Consumable' in itunesConnect, but after purchasing one item, it won't let me buy another one.

In my application user should be able to buy 'n' number of licenses, in PurchaseProduct Method just takes productID as parameter so I need to call this method multiple times.

I thought defining another Product like as 10-Licenses would be a good idea, but there is no relation between this two Products, and ConsumeProduct Method just takes a ProductID not the number of consumtion.

Since lack of resources about that, I appreciate if some one gives me some hints, or best practices.

p.s. Is storing the number of purchased products in application good idea?

Comment: Why -1? Add comments to understand why

Comment: Maybe this is 'as designed', ask the people who wrote the API this way (check their forum/FAQ first)

Comment: @mjn Thanks ,It can be done in Xamarin so I thought since it's new component in Delphi XE6 some might know, and might give me some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I don't know if it is correct or not:

I consume the product just right after purchasing, and I locally get the track of bought items.

Answer (score 0):

if productquery is fill with list, actually u can consume. i put try finally end statement, and put consumeproduct after try. and it will work,

what do u mean by locally get the track of bought items?